# Ruby on Rails: http://localhost:3000 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, localhost

Machines:

- VM Machine (Ruby on Rails Server) - 192.168.1.37
- Host Machine (Machine where the VM resides) - 192.168.1.38
- Remote Machine (Dev Machine) - 192.168.1.36

Notes

- VM Machine is running Cent OS (console only)
- Host Machine is running Windows 7
- VM emulator is Virtual Box
- Remote Machine is Running on Windows 10

Pre-requisite

- Added 192.168.1.37 as localhost in the Host Machine host file
- start the rails service `bundle exec rails s -p 3000`

Problem

- accessing site `http://localhost:3000` NOT working
- accessing site `https://192.168.1.37:3000` working

What Is Needed

- Access the site via `http://locahost:3000`

Quirks

- It works on remote machines running Linux (changed the host file to point to VM Machine as localhost)

Comment: which version of rails are you running?

Answer (score 3):

why do you insist to visit the site via localhost:3000? as you are running the app under vm, if you want to access the webpage from another pc/mac via ip, you have to forward the local port to the vm port via nat, or let the vm to own a ip from your local network.

As you can access the webpage via https://192.168.1.37:3000, rails is running, there's nothing to do with rails configurations.

Comment: the app is configured to run on the localhost:3000. If I use the 192.168.1.37:3000 the scripts does not execute.

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4 binds on `localhost` by default, so you will need to bind to `0.0.0.0`, if you want the page to be accessible from another machine.

Start your rails server like this:

```
bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0
```